# ADF Read Data From txt File And Assign to Variable

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I would like to extract data from text file and assign it into variable before they can commit to database. I able to read all the data inside the text file, unfortunately i fail to separate them and assign to certain variable. My code as below:

```
private RichInputFile inputFile;
private UploadedFile file;
private String fileContent;
private String fileName;
private InputStream inputstream; 

 public void onFileUploadValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    resetValue();
    file = (UploadedFile)valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
    try {

        inputstream = file.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("inputstream Name: " +inputstream);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onUploadFile(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (file != null && inputstream != null) {

        fileName = file.getFilename();
        System.out.println("Notepad Name: " +fileName);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        try {

            IOUtils.copy(inputstream, writer);
            fileContent = writer.toString();
            System.out.println("File Content: " +fileContent);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Notepad Content: " +writer);
    }

    if (inputFile != null) {

        inputFile.resetValue();
        inputFile.setValid(true);

    }
}

public void resetValue() {

    if (fileName != null)
        fileName = null;

    if (fileContent != null)
        fileContent = null;

    if (inputstream != null)
        inputstream = null;
}

public void setInputFile(RichInputFile inputFile) {
    this.inputFile = inputFile;

}

public RichInputFile getInputFile() {
    return inputFile;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public String getFileContent() {
    return fileContent;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
```

Mind to provide me some suggestion?

Comment: What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: Data in the test file was:
16/05/2014  17:19:00  6685  00:00:31
Meanwhile result i get was:
16/05/2014  17:19:00  6685  00:00:31
In the same string. I wish to separate them accordingly.Thxz~

Comment: is the data in the file on two lines or one?

Comment: @MihaiC below is the example of data in the file:
16/05/2014 17:19:00 6685 00:00:31
17/06/2014 17:19:00 6685 00:00:32
it contain multiple lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Split the line via separator

I'm assuming your input file contains each entry on one line.

In that case, replace `onUploadFile` with this code.

It uses `Scanner` to read the `inputstream` line by line. Do what you want with each line.

```
public void onUploadFile(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (file != null && inputstream != null) {
        fileName = file.getFilename();
        System.out.println("Notepad Name: " + fileName);

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputstream);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            //do somthing with the current line, like store each one in a list
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] lineElements=line.split(" ");
            //16/05/2014 17:19:00 6685 00:00:31
            //in your case lineElements[0] should be a date 
            //lineElements[1] is a timestamp linked to the before date 
            //lineElements[2] is a number (int)
            //lineElements[3] is a timestamp
            //build string from elements [0] and [1] then transform it to a date
            //add logic for adding to database...
        }
    }

    if (inputFile != null) {

        inputFile.resetValue();
        inputFile.setValid(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi your code is working fine. But i just wondering how you going to differential the data type? For example the data i read from notepad consist of date,string and number. How can i differential it and store in table?

Comment: well you mostly can't, unless you test each element of the line before. usually in these cases, you know the structure of the table and the structure of the file, they have to match beforehand. the alternative is to test each element of the line with eigther Integer.parseInt(), toString() , Date conversion etc before.

Comment: in your case you have to split the line by "space" character, then test each element, but i don't recommend this. you should know that the file always contains dates,integers,strings (for example) in that order! so when you get the elements like split[0] you know that it's a date. split the line with String[] split=line.split(" ");

Comment: MihaiC: yup~ i did it by using "Substring" function and it working well. Just need to do some conversion for certain data format.